# SQL Server windows Authentication connection issue

Tags: sql-server-2008

While i am installing SQL Server 2008, i selected mixed authentication mode. But after the installing while i am trying to connect with the database in Windows authentication it gives the following error :

```
TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to DEWASISH-PC\SQLEXPRESS.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Login failed for user 'dewasish-PC\dewasish'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=18456&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

But when in am trying the same with SQL Server authentication mode, I am able to connect with the database. Can any one tell me in what manner i able to connect with the database with the help of windows authentication ?

Answer (score 0):

In your instance Security you'll need to add either:

1. Your Windows login name as a Windows login user, including domain if applicable, or
2. If you are a member of a Windows domain security group, add the group name as a Windows login user.

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio -> Object Explorer -> Connect as `sa` -> Security